# Python read_excel ignore data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I downloading file where in one column, there is user comment. Sometimes comment begin with "-". When I am opening file in `excel`, `excel` is automatically adding "=" before value and at the end there is #NAME? in cell.

For example: instead of having `"- comment"` i have `"=-comment"` in `excel`.

When I try to import this file by python using panda.read_excel, python ignores that values and treat them as `NaN`.

As process must be automatic and file if big I cannot clean data manually every time. Also cannot convert file to `csv`.

I tried: `data_only=False, data_only=True, dtype=str` but none of that solved my problem.

I want python to read that values as text instead of ignore them.

Comment: Can we see a sample of this data?

Comment: this is because excel is reading `-` as a mathematical operator and not a string so `- comment` is not valid.What is your source file, csv or xlsx?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share data and yes, that because excel is interpreting - as mathematical operator. Source is xlsx. I have some internal company tool, which I am taking data from. There is only option "save as excel". This automatically generate file witch is changing comments beginning with "-" to formula (wrong formula so #NAME?). then pd.read_excel is ignoring that and reading as NaN. So even when I try to convert values using some custom functions it is doing that on NaN not on value.